# Get size of an Iterable in Java

Tags: java, iterable

I need to figure out the number of elements in an `Iterable` in Java.
I know I can do this:

```
Iterable values = ...
it = values.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  it.next();
  sum++;
}
```

I could also do something like this, because I do not need the objects in the Iterable any further:

```
it = values.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  it.remove();
  sum++;
}
```

A small scale benchmark did not show much performance difference, any comments or other ideas for this problem?

Comment: Why? Either is a really bad idea, as both are O(N). You should try to avoid having to iterate the collection twice.

Comment: Your second one shouldn't even work.  You can't call `remove()` without calling `next()` beforehand.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

**TL;DR: Use the utility method [`Iterables.size(Iterable)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size(java.lang.Iterable)) of the great [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library.**

Of your two code snippets, you should use the first one, because the second one will remove all elements from `values`, so it is empty afterwards. Changing a data structure for a simple query like its size is very unexpected.

For performance, this depends on your data structure. If it is for example in fact an `ArrayList`, removing elements from the beginning (what your second method is doing) is very slow (calculating the size becomes O(n*n) instead of O(n) as it should be).

In general, if there is the chance that `values` is actually a `Collection` and not only an `Iterable`, check this and call `size()` in case:

```
if (values instanceof Collection<?>) {
  return ((Collection<?>)values).size();
}
// use Iterator here...
```

The call to `size()` will usually be much faster than counting the number of elements, and this trick is exactly what [`Iterables.size(Iterable)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#size(java.lang.Iterable)) of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) does for you.

Comment: He says that he's not interested in the elements and doesn't care if they are removed though.

Comment: Small clarification: it will remove the elements *from `values`*

Comment: But other parts of the code might still be using the same Iterable. And if not now, perhaps in the future.

Comment: I suggest making the Google Guava answer more prominent. There's no reason to make people write this code again, even though it's trivial.

Comment: @StephenHarrison Thanks, this is a good idea, I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: If you use Java 8, create a Stream and count element in it as:

Stream.of(myIterable).count()

Comment: Just beware that calling this on an Iterable object that has been assigned will not return the same result twice: List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("yo");
list.add("blah");
list.add("ok");
System.out.println("1st call: "+Iterators.size(list.iterator()));
System.out.println("2nd call: "+Iterators.size(list.iterator()));

Iterator<String> iterObj = list.iterator();
System.out.println("1st call on obj: "+Iterators.size(iterObj));
System.out.println("2nd call on obj: "+Iterators.size(iterObj)); 
yields 1st call: 3
2nd call: 3
1st call on obj: 3
2nd call on obj: 0

Comment: @mancini0 You are confusing Iterables and Iterators. This question is about Iterables, and for Iterables everything works fine. Your example code demonstrates only that the similar utility method that happens to exist for Iterators exhausts the Iterator, but this has nothing to do with the code from this answer.

Comment: What if my iterator is like ```Iterator<IntWritable>```

Answer (score 51):

If you are working with java 8 you may use:

```
Iterable values = ...
long size = values.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown();
```

it will only work if the iterable source has a determined size. Most Spliterators for Collections will, but you may have issues if it comes from a `HashSet`or `ResultSet`for instance.

You can check the [javadoc here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#estimateSize--)

**If Java 8 is not an option**, or if you don't know where the iterable comes from, you can use the same approach as guava:

```
  if (iterable instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection<?>) iterable).size();
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        Iterator iterator = iterable.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterator.next();
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Somebody, hand this guy a medal.

Comment: It doesn't work for me for [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) . Answer by New Bee works for me.

Answer (score 19):

This is perhaps a bit late, but may help someone. I come across similar issue with `Iterable` in my codebase and solution was to use `for each` without explicitly calling `values.iterator();`.

```
int size = 0;
for(T value : values) {
   size++;
}
```

Comment: This is, to me, an intuitive approach, which I can appreciate. Just used it a few minutes ago. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's intuitive, but sadly you have to suppress an unused-warning for value...

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it indeed returns the size of the object. The only backside is that if you want to iterate again later through the same object, then first you should reset it somehow.

Answer (score 8):

You can cast your iterable to a list then use .size() on it.

```
Lists.newArrayList(iterable).size();
```

For the sake of clarity, the above method will require the following import:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

Comment: Lists is a Guava class

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, Iterable does not have size.  Think data structure like a cycle.

And think about following Iterable instance, No size:

```
    new Iterable(){

        @Override public Iterator iterator() {
            return new Iterator(){

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return isExternalSystemAvailble();
                }

                @Override
                public Object next() {
                    return fetchDataFromExternalSystem();
                }};
        }};
```

Answer (score 4):

java 8 and above

```
StreamSupport.stream(data.spliterator(), false).count();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `it.next()` for the simple reason that `next()` is guaranteed to be implemented, while `remove()` is an optional operation.

> ```
> E next()
> ```
>
> Returns the next element in the iteration.
>
> ```
> void remove()
> ```
>
> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by the iterator **(optional operation)**.

Comment: While this answer is _technically_ correct, it's quite misleading. Calling `remove` has already been noted as the wrong way to count elements of an  `Iterator`, so it doesn't really matter whether the thing we're not going to do is implemented or not.

Comment: Exactly which part of the answer is misleading? And under the circumstance where `remove` *is* implemented, why would it be wrong to use it? Btw, downvotes are typicallt used for wrong answers or answers that give bad advice. I can't see how this answer qualifies for any of that.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, these are just different methods. The first one leaves the object you're iterating on unchanged, while the seconds leaves it empty.
The question is what do you want to do.
The complexity of removing is based on implementation of your iterable object.
If you're using Collections - just obtain the size like was proposed by Kazekage Gaara - its usually the best approach performance wise.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you simply use the `size()` method on your `Collection` to get the number of elements?

`Iterator` is just meant to iterate,nothing else.

Comment: Who says he's using a collection? :-)

Comment: You are using an iterator, which supports removal of elements. If you pick up the size before entering the iterator loop, you need to be careful with your removals and update the value accordingly.

Comment: An example of why he may not have a collection to look at for size: he could be calling a third-party API method that returns only an Iterable.

Comment: This answer confuses `Iterator` and `Iterable`. See the voted answer for the correct way.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using loops and counting each element or using and third party library we can simply typecast the iterable in ArrayList and get its size.

```
((ArrayList) iterable).size();
```

Comment: Not all iterables can be cast to ArrayList tho