# Sonarqube complaining about unused variable in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, sonarqube, iterable, unused-variables

In my project I have a simple function that calculates the length of an iterable (as I don't think there is an easy way to get it? No `.size()` or `.length()` is accepted?) Here is the code:

```
public int getIterableSize(Iterable<User> users){
        int size = 0;

        for(User user : users){
            size++;
        }

        return size;
    }
```

I also use Sonarqube to keep my code quality and I get the following code smell about this function:

> Remove this unused "user" local variable.

There must be an easy way to get rid of this right? Maybe an alternative for the for loop, maybe a different function provided by iterable?

Comment: your function can return like this. `return users.stream().count();`

Comment: @PandeyAmit iterable doesn't seem to have a function for stream()

Comment: Which type is `users`?

Comment: @EldarB. it's an iterable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get size of an Iterable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598977/get-size-of-an-iterable-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate it with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`.

Either the method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public int getIterableSize(Iterable<User> users){
    int size = 0;

    for(User user : users){
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Or the variable:

```
public int getIterableSize(Iterable<User> users){
    int size = 0;

    for(@SuppressWarnings("unused") User user : users){
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Various IDEs can automatically offer both of these fixes.